# How can I extend the timeout of a context in Go?

Tags: go

For example, the context is created with timeout to be 10 seconds later.
After a while (e.g. 2 seconds later), I want to refresh it to be 10 seconds later from this time.

What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) is not designed that way. `context.Context` is delegated down to workers, and if a worker finds that more time should be allowed, it can't override the "master's call".

If you have a situation where an initial 10 seconds timeout is to be used, but this 10 seconds is not written in stone (e.g. it may change before it expires), then don't use a context with 10 seconds timeout. Instead use a context with a cancel function: [`context.WithCancel()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel), and manage the 10 seconds timeout yourself (e.g. with [`time.AfterFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc) or with a [`time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer)). If the timeout has expired and you (or your workers) did not detect that it should be extended, call the cancel function.

If before the deadline you detect the timeout should be extended, reset the timer and do not cancel the context with the cancel function.

Comment: just a doubt. related to the question can we do something like this https://play.golang.org/p/8Sx1yLXtRVb ? .

Comment: @SivaGuru That might work in a single example, but it's bad practice. E.g. the 2nd context's cancel function is not handled. The first context also remains unfreed until its deadline expires. Also if there are other cases and work involved, things might get complicated. Also note that `select` only evaluates the cases once, so if `ctx` is changed while the `select` waits, the new context's channel will not be used only when reentering `select` again.

Comment: i thought it was a bad idea needed some clarification. Ty for explaining.